# Should I Dispose() a SqlConnection if I don't open() it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dispose, sqlconnection

We are having occasional SqlServer lock-ups requiring a restart and I'm reviewing legacy code to try and isolate causes.

In a Library file that is included in every c# ASP.Net page I find this:

```
sConString  = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("SQLConnString"); 
oCon = new SqlConnection(sConString);
```

If a page does database access it starts with

```
oCon.Open();
```

and ends with:

```
oCon.Close();   
oCon.Dispose();
```

But some pages dont do database access so there is no `Dispose();` called.

My question is, is there an overhead caused by creating a `SqlConnection` that doesnt get `Disposed()`?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I don't see, why a connection that hasn't been opened is causing server lockup. As far as `Dispose` goes, CLR automatically takes care of it. Only thing to worry about is that every `open` should have a corresponding `close`.

Comment: Why are you creating it if you're not using it?

Comment: @AustinSalonen, the connection is created by a global function library that is included in each page

Comment: @Abhinav, how quickly does CLR remove the connection? I'll try adding a `dispose()` at the end of a few test pages to evalute effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispose() has more to do with memory management than connection management. I don't think this will solve your issue. You might want to make sure you close your connection in the finally block of a Try-Catch. This way the connection will be closed if your open connection is successful or not.

Comment: Thanks Jason. You comments supported what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `Dispose` if connection isn't opened, when you create SQL connection instance it is just normal managed resource which will be disposed automatically by CLR. Anyway it is a good practice to close or dispose any SQL connection in terms of flexibility and maintainability.